# Why isn't a python string a subclass of list?

Tags: python

This honestly just feels super weird to me. I've been learning python for only a couple of days, but I can't help but feel weirded out at the fact that list and string are treated differently in some cases, most notably in the fact that strings are immutable. Was it made like this because there isn't a real character object in python, so strings couldn't have been treated as a list of characters? I am probably talking gibberish, but I still hope someone much more knowledgeable could perhaps give me some further insight into this.

Comment: It can't be a subclass _because_ it's immutable, you can't _substitute_ (thanks [Barbara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)) a string where a list is expected because you can't assign into it by index. They're related via https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence, a string is more similar to a tuple than a list.

Comment: And strings are immutable not by accident or because someone messed up but by design.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that strings are immutable is (among other things) a question of performance. This allows great optimizations, which are nice to have because strings are used a lot.

Incidentally, you can also have lists of characters, if you wanted to, so it is easy to have both mutable and immutable strings this way. However, if strings were actually lists of characters, it would be harder in python to make what strings currently are, meaning it would be easy to have mutable strings, but hard to have immutable ones.

As pointed out by a comment, this immutability is the reason why strings are not subclasses of lists.

An other reason is that the `list` class in python does not represent any sequential type, just what are usually called dynamic arrays in other languages. For instance, functional programming languages usually call linked lists `list`. This means that it's not just because a `str` can be viewed as a sequence type that it should inherit `list`. However, this is still true: `str`, just as `list`, can be viewed as a sequence type, which is why it is an `iterable`. This kind of interface, in Python, does not work with subclassing, but just with duck-typing, so `str` does not need to inherit from any `iterable` super-class to be one (in particular, it needs not to inherit from `list`).